# Reactionrole does not work with custom emoji but will work using default ones

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Hi everyone I have been trying to make my reactionrole work for a bit now and have run into a problem. So far my bot doesnt seem to work using a **custom emoji** on my own discord server but seems to run fine with default ones I used a default and custom one to check. I don't get a log for 2 so it seems to go wrong there. I also tried changing `reaction.emoji.name` to `id` but with no result. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const yellowTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Iron");
    const blueTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Gold");

    const yellowTeamEmoji = '<:Iron:1006186923917852712>';
    const blueTeamEmoji = '';

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#e42643')
        .setTitle('Choose a team to play on!')
        .setDescription('Choosing a team will allow you to interact with your teammates!\n\n'
            + `${yellowTeamEmoji} for yellow team\n`
            + `${blueTeamEmoji} for blue team`);

    let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
    messageEmbed.react(yellowTeamEmoji);
    messageEmbed.react(blueTeamEmoji);

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
        if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
        if (user.bot) return;
        if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

        if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
            console.log('1');
            if (reaction.emoji.name === yellowTeamEmoji) {
                console.log('2');
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(yellowTeamRole);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === blueTeamEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(blueTeamRole);
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't get a log because in your `if` statement you're comparing the whole emote to only its name.

You're basically doing this:
`if("Iron" === "<:Iron:1006186923917852712>")`

What you should do is get the emote in your client or guild and access the name property through `.name`

```
 // the id of your emote
const foundEmote = client.emojis.cache.find(e => e.id === "1006186923917852712");

if(reaction.emoji.name === foundEmote.name) {
// your code
}
```